# 2 place in the page with the same XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want to insert text into a file. This file `xpath = "//*[@id='email']"`.
This XPath is moved to 2 places in the web page. The first is not visible and the second is OK. I want to insert text to the second. I do it like this:

```
String xpathOfElement = "//*[@id='email']";

List<WebElement> a = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathOfElement));
a.get(1).sendKeys("hhh");
```

I received this error message:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: Can you share HTML for both nodes?

Comment: what to you mean? the url?

Comment: Try with the index as 0, as the first one is not visible it will not be found...

Comment: @Grasshopper Index 0 - i received a msg that it is not visible. I need the second one.

Comment: According to your error message, there aren't two elements that match that locator. Either you have the wrong locator or you need to add a wait so that both show up. Either way, you need to provide the HTML or a link to the page. Also, please please please don't use XPath when you have an ID... there's no point. Just use `By.id("email")`... it will be easier to read, easier to maintain, better supported, and execute faster.

Answer (score 0):

@libi Yes, if you could provide the url I can help you write xpath. You might want to take a look at **[Xpath Cheat Sheet](https://devhints.io/xpath)**.

My suggestion is to include the parent/sibling to make your xpath **unique**. For example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="email">
  E-mail:
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <input type="submit">
</div>
<br>
<div class="email2">
  E-mail 2:
  <input type="email" name="email2">
  <input type="submit">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Xpath for Email   :** `//div[@class="email"]/input[@type="email"]`

**Xpath for Email 2 :** `//div[@class="email2"]/input[@type="email"]`

Answer (score 0):

As per the details you have provided in your question, the error which you are observing as below is pretty correct :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

### Analysis

As you mentioned `This XPath is moved to 2 places in the web page. The first is not visible and the second is OK. I want to insert text to the second.`, so whenever you :

```
String xpathOfElement = "//*[@id='email']";
List<WebElement> a = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathOfElement));
```

Only he second element you mentioned is stored in the **`List a`**. As the first element is **not visible** **`Selenium`** is unable to recognize it's **visibility** in the **`DOM Tree`**. So, **`List<WebElement> a`** will contain a single `WebElement` as :

```
[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (52a50170-91f5-4211-ae81-a72f0d863714)] -> xpath: //*[@id='email']]]
```

So, next when you try to :

```
a.get(1).sendKeys("hhh");
```

**`a.get(1)`** refers to the second element in the `List` which location is neither initialized not contains any value. Hence you see :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

### Solution:

The simple solution would be to construct a unique logical `css` or `xpath` for the visible (`OK`) element. To achieve that **`String xpathOfElement = "//*[@id='email']";`** is not enough. You have to traverse up the `DOM` and find the parent node and construct a unique `xpath` and proceed as follows :

```
String unique_xpathOfElement = "//*[@id='email']";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(unique_xpathOfElement)).sendKeys("hhh");
```

The other way is the way you tried out but instead of `index` as **1**, you have to **`get()`** the `index` **0** as follows :

```
String xpathOfElement = "//*[@id='email']".sendKeys("hhh");
List<WebElement> a = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathOfElement));
a.get(0).sendKeys("hhh");
```